# How to find out which authentication provider an user was using in Django

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I'm using django-social-auth for authentication. How do I figure out which social authentication backend was the `request.user` using when my social auth `User` model is `django.contrib.auth.models.User`?

The purpose is to show an icon (e.g. twitter, facebook, big G) next to user "profile" / logout link in the base template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [django-social-auth's template context processors](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/v0.7.22/configuration.html#template-context-processors). For example, if you add the `social_auth_backends` processor, then

```
{{ social_auth.associated }}
```

would show a list of `UserSocialAuth` instances associated with current user.